Jammed drawer slides (metal) are not sliding easily - black dirt
The slides are sliding unsmoothly. There is also a lot of black dirt. Could it be that the grease that was used by the manufacturer dried up? How should I fix this.



Grease doesn't really dry up.  It's most likely that it's sucked up dirt/dust/grime over the years—possibly particles coming off the plastic or metal parts of the tracks too.  Clean it off with a good solvent and regrease.

It's likely that the black dirt was black dirt, not the manufacturer's grease.
Give them critters a really good clean-out, with a few back and forths after the major amount of dirt is removed. Use some rubbing alcohol to clean out old dirty grease, then add new grease, probably regular car grease will do. Not much is needed, just a little dab to get those slides running like new.
